# Why using state manager like Zustand component still re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, state, zustand

From my understanding if i change state in component this will cause the component to re-render, but in this case I'm using Zustand to store the values outside of the component but why is my component still being re-render every time i scroll / update Zustand state?

To test, scroll on the window and have console open, this will show console.log being fired every time i scroll / update Zustand state.

Made sample demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-stonebraker-rivjo?file=/src/App.js

Code App.js

```
import { stateButton } from "./stateButton";
import { Scrollbar } from "react-scrollbars-custom";

export default function App() {
  const { setBtn } = stateButton();

  console.log("rendering");

  return (
    <div>
      <Scrollbar
        style={{ width: "250px", height: "50px" }}
        onScroll={() => setBtn(1)}
      >
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Test</div>
      </Scrollbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Zustand state:

```
import create, { GetState, SetState } from "zustand";

export type typeBtn = {
  getBtn: number;
  setBtn: (item: number) => void;
};

export const stateButton = create<typeBtn>(
  (set: SetState<typeBtn>, get: GetState<typeBtn>) => ({
    getBtn: 0,
    setBtn: (item) => set({ getBtn: item })
  })
);
```

Comment: Isn't that what it's suposed to do? For as far as i know thats default behaviour.

Comment: i thought the same, but i thought if i use the getBtn on a component then it should re-render it but for now i'm setting it only. if thats default then i just had a wrong impression of this, but still curious then how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it

```
  const tempBtn = stateButton((state) => state.setBtn);
```

and

```
onScroll={() => tempBtn(1)}
```